# Inherit CSS classes in styled-components definitions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to style my app using `styled-components` where my components inherit styles from existing globally defined CSS. In the example below, how can I make `Surface` inherit the classes `.raised` and `.bordered` so that I don't have to repeat `className="raised bordered"` in each usage?  I want something similar to [Composition in Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition).

https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-ramanujan-xs8rt

`App.js`

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Surface className="raised bordered">Hello World 1</Surface>
    <Surface className="raised bordered">Hello World 2</Surface>
    <Surface className="raised bordered">Hello World 3</Surface>
  </div>
);

const Surface = styled.div`
  color: darkblue;
  margin: 20px;
`;

export default App;
```

`styles.css`

```
.raised {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.bordered {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You can do composition here too, how you intent to "inherit" it without writing this css somewhere? Are you asking what is the syntax?

Comment: The CSS is written in `styles.css`. I could define it anywhere though, my question is how to inherit CSS class styles on a `styled-components` definition. The core question in my OP is `how can I make Surface inherit the classes .raised and .bordered so that I don't have to repeat className="raised bordered" in each usage`. Is there a syntax to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is doable using `attrs` as shown below

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Surface>Hello World 1</Surface>
    <Surface>Hello World 2</Surface>
    <Surface>Hello World 3</Surface>
  </>
);

const Surface = styled.div.attrs({
  className: "raised bordered"
})`
  color: darkblue;
  margin: 20px;
`;

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If i'm right understood, you want customize component without external `css` and use it anywhere in the project. Easiest way use is props. second more complex create for each `.raised` and  `.bordered` it's own styles components. [easiest way example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-euler-qlll8?file=/src/App.js:24-283)

**App.js**

```
import { Surface } from "./Surface";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Surface bordered>Hello World 1</Surface>
    <Surface boxShadow>Hello World 2</Surface>
    <Surface bordered boxShadow>
      Hello World 3
    </Surface>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

**Surface.js**

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const SurfaceStyle = styled.div`
  color: darkblue;
  margin: 20px;
  ${({ bordered }) => bordered && "border: 1px solid black"};
  ${({ boxShadow }) =>
    boxShadow && "box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;"}
`;

export const Surface = ({ bordered, boxShadow, children }) => {
  return (
    <SurfaceStyle bordered={bordered} boxShadow={boxShadow}>
      {children}
    </SurfaceStyle>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When talking about applying styling on all the elements inside, adding a parent class for all the Surface elements will work.

Try this-

`App.js`

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="combined">
    <Surface className="raised bordered">Hello World 1</Surface>
    <Surface className="raised bordered">Hello World 2</Surface>
    <Surface className="raised bordered">Hello World 3</Surface>
  </div>
);
```

`Styles.css`

```
.combined div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
```

Comment: I want the styles or classes to be tied to the actual definition of `Surface` though. Raising the className up a level isn't composition - it wouldn't work if I reused the `Surface` element in other places outside that wrapper div. This would also style all elements I add inside the wrapper div not just `Surface` elements